# Como redireccionar ou voltar atrás automáticamente para a página anterior?

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho este código php e js na página de login, ele redirecciona para outra página ao fim de 4 segundos, mas eu queria que ela redireccionasse para a página anterior ou de origem que tinha enviado o utilizador para esta página de login. Como fazer isso, porque já testei muitas vezes e não consigo fazê-lo.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
      $clubeSorte->mensagemSucesso("Login feito com sucesso! Será redirecionado brevemente. Se não for redirecionado clique <a href='".URL_PESQUISA."'>aqui</a>");

      ?>

     <script>$(document).ready(function(){
        function redirect(){
          window.location = "<?php echo URL_PESQUISA; ?>";
        }
        setTimeout(redirect, 4000);
      });</script>
```

Comment: Talvez `window.history.go(-1);` no javascript te ajude.

Comment: Ok funcionou mas tive de colocar window.history.go(-2); ... Aliás eu antes já tinha testado isto mas devia estar mal colocado ou com erro. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolvido**, pode manter todas as funções e basta substituir a parte do js window.location = ""; por window.history.go(-1);

**Fica assim o código completo:**
$clubeSorte->mensagemSucesso("Login feito com sucesso! Será redirecionado brevemente. Se não for redirecionado clique aqui");

```
  ?>

 <script>$(document).ready(function(){
        function redirect(){
          window.history.go(-2);
        }
        setTimeout(redirect, 4000);
      });</script>
```